# How to set data in custom Web Property SharePoint online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, powershell, jsom, managed-property

Could you help me please, how can I set a value to custom web property in SharePoint and then get this property later?

Now, I only can get all default properties using `[web url]/_api/web`.

Comment: Hi @Propool, did you try solution given below? is it working for you? let me know if you still need help with this.

Comment: I am checking to see how things are going there on this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PnP PowerShell to set a value to custom web property in SharePoint online.

**Example**:

```
Set-PnPPropertyBagValue -Key MyKey -Value MyValue
```

Then you can retrieve web property using:

```
Get-PnPPropertyBag -Key MyKey
```

**Documentation**: [Set-PnPPropertyBagValue](https://pnp.github.io/powershell/cmdlets/Set-PnPPropertyBagValue.html)

Comment: If you want to do it using JSOM, you can try this: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/dec51c53-1873-43cb-81e2-5f1239513299/how-do-you-assign-spweb-property-bag-values-in-jsom